# How to "dissect" combinatorial problems and decide which solution method to use?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm currently studying combinatorics and I'm finding it difficult to know how to approach some problems. While some seem obvious in their solution others are much harder.

While this is a somewhat vague question I wonder: Is there a general way to approach all/most (college level) combinatorial problems and then decide upon which solution method to use (like a decision tree)?

Thanks

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the specific problem at hand, and writing a full decision tree to describe what you should do is not easily done.  Not to mention, there are many problems where there are multiple correct approaches.  In the end, each time you see a new innovative solution using a technique you haven't seen before, try to learn how and why that technique works and store it in your bag of tricks.  Be familiar with inclusion-exclusion, multiplication principle, partitions, generating functions, recursion, etc...

Comment: Another tip, is when seeing a new problem for the first time, try to see if you can reword it in a useful convenient way into a problem that you already know the answer to.  For example, counting number of functions satisfying $x<y\Rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)$ can be related to counting the number of integer lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ which use only rights and ups, which can further be related to counting the number of sequences of r's and u's of a specific length with a specific number of r's...  You can hopefully reword it down to a simple well known problem type.